# Api returns nothing (with hitbtc api and npmjs request addon)

Tags: javascript, node.js

EDIT: Thanks everyone, got it working using curlconverter. https://www.npmjs.com/package/curlconverter

Here is the working code:

```
var dataString = 'symbol=LTCUSD&side=sell&quantity=0.1&type=market&timeInForce=FOK';

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/order',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString,
    auth: {
        'user': api_key_hitbtc,
        'pass': api_secret_hitbtc
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(response)
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

I'm trying to code program to send commands to hitbtc (https://api.hitbtc.com/) api with nodejs request (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). I already have code for authed request to fetch account balances working fine, but somehow I cant get sending orders work. Currently I have the following code:

```
      var request = require("request");
      var api_key_hitbtc = 'mykey';
      var api_secret_hitbtc = 'mysecret';

      hitbtc_sell_url = 'https://' + api_key_hitbtc + ':' +     api_secret_hitbtc + '@api.hitbtc.com/api/2/order';

        request({url: hitbtc_sell_url, json: true, postData: {
    mimeType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    params: [
      {
        symbol: 'LTCUSD',
        side: 'sell', 
        type: 'market', 
        quantity: '0.08'
      }
    ]
  }}, function (error, response, body) {
              console.log(body);

            });
```

The following code outputs: []
Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? Thanks!

Edit: error returns null and response returns following code:

```
     IncomingMessage {
     _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function] ],
     close: [ [Function], [Function] ],
     data: [Function],
     error: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket:
   TLSSocket {
     _tlsOptions:
      { pipe: null,
        secureContext: [Object],
        isServer: false,
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        session: undefined,
        NPNProtocols: undefined,
        ALPNProtocols: undefined,
        requestOCSP: undefined },
     _secureEstablished: true,
     _securePending: false,
     _newSessionPending: false,
     _controlReleased: true,
     _SNICallback: null,
     servername: null,
     npnProtocol: false,
     alpnProtocol: false,
     authorized: true,
     authorizationError: null,
     encrypted: true,
     _events:
      { close: [Object],
        end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        secure: [Function],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 9,
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'api.hitbtc.com',
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 207,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: undefined,
     _server: null,
     ssl: null,
     _requestCert: true,
     _rejectUnauthorized: true,
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /api/2/order HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: api.hitbtc.com\r\nauthorization: Basic MYAUTH naccept: application/json\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/2/order',
        _ended: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  connection:
   TLSSocket {
     _tlsOptions:
      { pipe: null,
        secureContext: [Object],
        isServer: false,
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        session: undefined,
        NPNProtocols: undefined,
        ALPNProtocols: undefined,
        requestOCSP: undefined },
     _secureEstablished: true,
     _securePending: false,
     _newSessionPending: false,
     _controlReleased: true,
     _SNICallback: null,
     servername: null,
     npnProtocol: false,
     alpnProtocol: false,
     authorized: true,
     authorizationError: null,
     encrypted: true,
     _events:
      { close: [Object],
        end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        secure: [Function],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 9,
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'api.hitbtc.com',
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 207,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: undefined,
     _server: null,
     ssl: null,
     _requestCert: true,
     _rejectUnauthorized: true,
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /api/2/order HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: api.hitbtc.com\r\nauthorization: Basic  MYAUTH naccept: application/json\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/2/order',
        _ended: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: true,
  headers:
   { server: 'nginx',
     date: 'Mon, 08 Jan 2018 07:21:02 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'content-length': '2',
     connection: 'close' },
  rawHeaders:
   [ 'Server',
     'nginx',
     'Date',
     'Mon, 08 Jan 2018 07:21:02 GMT',
     'Content-Type',
     'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'Content-Length',
     '2',
     'Connection',
     'close' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '',
  method: null,
  statusCode: 200,
  statusMessage: 'OK',
  client:
   TLSSocket {
     _tlsOptions:
      { pipe: null,
        secureContext: [Object],
        isServer: false,
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        session: undefined,
        NPNProtocols: undefined,
        ALPNProtocols: undefined,
        requestOCSP: undefined },
     _secureEstablished: true,
     _securePending: false,
     _newSessionPending: false,
     _controlReleased: true,
     _SNICallback: null,
     servername: null,
     npnProtocol: false,
     alpnProtocol: false,
     authorized: true,
     authorizationError: null,
     encrypted: true,
     _events:
      { close: [Object],
        end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        secure: [Function],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 9,
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'api.hitbtc.com',
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 207,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: undefined,
     _server: null,
     ssl: null,
     _requestCert: true,
     _rejectUnauthorized: true,
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /api/2/order HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: api.hitbtc.com\r\nauthorization: Basic MYAUTH naccept: application/json\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/2/order',
        _ended: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  _consuming: true,
  _dumped: false,
  req:
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { socket: [Function],
        response: [Function: bound ],
        error: [Function: bound ],
        drain: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 5,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedHeader: {},
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'api.hitbtc.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: true,
        _bytesDispatched: 207,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1 },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'api.hitbtc.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: true,
        _bytesDispatched: 207,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1 },
     _header: 'GET /api/2/order HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: api.hitbtc.com\r\nauthorization: Basic MYAUTH \naccept: application/json\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _headers:
      { host: 'api.hitbtc.com',
        authorization: 'Basic MYAUTH',
        accept: 'application/json' },
     _headerNames:
      { host: 'host',
        authorization: 'authorization',
        accept: 'accept' },
     _onPendingData: null,
     agent:
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/api/2/order',
     _ended: true,
     parser: null,
     res: [Circular] },
  request:
   Request {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { error: [Function: bound ],
        complete: [Function: bound ],
        pipe: [Function],
        data: [Function],
        end: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 5,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     postData:
      { mimeType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        params: [Object] },
     callback: [Function],
     readable: true,
     writable: true,
     _qs:
      Querystring {
        request: [Circular],
        lib: [Object],
        useQuerystring: undefined,
        parseOptions: {},
        stringifyOptions: {} },
     _auth:
      Auth {
        request: [Circular],
        hasAuth: true,
        sentAuth: true,
        bearerToken: null,
        user: 'MYKEY',
        pass: 'MYSECRET' },
     _oauth: OAuth { request: [Circular], params: null },
     _multipart:
      Multipart {
        request: [Circular],
        boundary: 'MY BOUNDARY NUM',
        chunked: false,
        body: null },
     _redirect:
      Redirect {
        request: [Circular],
        followRedirect: true,
        followRedirects: true,
        followAllRedirects: false,
        followOriginalHttpMethod: false,
        allowRedirect: [Function],
        maxRedirects: 10,
        redirects: [],
        redirectsFollowed: 0,
        removeRefererHeader: false },
     _tunnel:
      Tunnel {
        request: [Circular],
        proxyHeaderWhiteList: [Object],
        proxyHeaderExclusiveList: [] },
     headers:
      { authorization: 'Basic MYAUTH',
        accept: 'application/json' },
     setHeader: [Function],
     hasHeader: [Function],
     getHeader: [Function],
     removeHeader: [Function],
     method: 'GET',
     localAddress: undefined,
     pool: {},
     dests: [],
     __isRequestRequest: true,
     _callback: [Function],
     uri:
      Url {
        protocol: 'https:',
        slashes: true,
        auth: 'mykey',
        host: 'api.hitbtc.com',
        port: 443,
        hostname: 'api.hitbtc.com',
        hash: null,
        search: null,
        query: null,
        pathname: '/api/2/order',
        path: '/api/2/order',
        href: 'https://mykey:mysecret@api.hitbtc.com/api/2/order' },
     proxy: null,
     tunnel: true,
     setHost: true,
     originalCookieHeader: undefined,
     _disableCookies: true,
     _jar: undefined,
     port: 443,
     host: 'api.hitbtc.com',
     path: '/api/2/order',
     _json: true,
     httpModule:
      { Server: [Object],
        createServer: [Function],
        globalAgent: [Object],
        Agent: [Object],
        request: [Function],
        get: [Function] },
     agentClass: { [Function: Agent] super_: [Object] },
     agent:
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     _started: true,
     href: 'https://mykey:mysecret@api.hitbtc.com/api/2/order',
     req:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'GET /api/2/order HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: api.hitbtc.com\r\nauthorization: Basic XXMYAUTH naccept: application/json\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/2/order',
        _ended: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     ntick: true,
     response: [Circular],
     originalHost: 'api.hitbtc.com',
     originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
     responseContent: [Circular],
     _destdata: true,
     _ended: true,
     _callbackCalled: true },
  toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
  caseless:
   Caseless {
     dict:
      { server: 'nginx',
        date: 'Mon, 08 Jan 2018 07:21:02 GMT',
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'content-length': '2',
        connection: 'close' } },
  read: [Function],
  body: [] }
```

Also if this helps someone to solve the problem, the following is the right way to do the curl request (in api docs):

```
  curl -X PUT -u "apikey:apisecret" \
      "https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/order/randomorderidhere" \
       -d 'symbol=ETHBTC&side=sell&quantity=0.063&price=0.046016'
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `error` or `response`?

Comment: Yes error returns nothing (null) and will post response soon

Comment: from your response it's clear that body is []; so either you are calling the wrong api or something is wrong with the way api is exposed.

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram Hmm, I was thinking that it must have to do somehing with sending parameters, since if I request without any parameters (only with order id on randomorderidhere) api still returns following message fine:
{ error: { code: 20002, message: 'Order not found', description: '' } }

Comment: it looks like you want to make a `PUT` request? The `request` npm package defaults to `GET` if you dont provide a method in the options

Comment: @Aaalex Paste the code where the api is defined; we can help u debug.

Comment: I actually got something forward, changing request type to post returns    { code: 2001,
     message: 'Symbol not found',
     description: 'Try get /api/2/public/symbol, to get list of all available symbols.' } } 
so it just means parameters are probably wrong right?

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram what do you mean? it isnt defined anywhere in the code

Comment: @Aaalex Somewhere in your project there is a piece of code that defines this ===> Upon hitting 'this url' give 'this response'; find that.

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram Hi this is full code, I dont have any other addonn/include than request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the request package [options parameter documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback). The parameter `postData` you used is not part of the request options definition. It is a suboption for [HAR requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#support-for-har-12)

To PUT/POST data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you can add a `form` parameter to the options object.

```
var request = require("request");

var orderUrl = 'https://...';
var orderParams = {
  symbol: 'LTCUSD',
  side: 'sell', 
  type: 'market', 
  quantity: '0.08'
};

request({
  url: orderUrl,
  method: 'POST',
  form: orderParams,
}, function(err, response, body){
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers, I just got it working using https://www.npmjs.com/package/curlconverter This answer is also working for me so case solved! Thanks!